# Azure Mobile Service calls hangs

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Using Xamarin.Forms app. When mobile data connection fluctuates on Android devices, e.g. network from 3G to 2G connection, or vice versa - the call seems to get hung somewhere.

This is the Azure API call :

```
public Task<ObservableCollection<Models.Item>> GetItemsByID(string tenantID, string auth_token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var res = RestClient.Get<ObservableCollection<Models.Item>>(HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(EndPointsList.GetItemsUrl + "tenantID={0}", tenantID)),auth_token);
            return res ;
        });
    }
```

We initiate the System.Net.WebRequest here :

```
        public static T Get<T>(WebRequest request, string auth_token, string requestData = null)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["ZUMO-API-VERSION"] = "2.0.0";

        if (auth_token.StartsWith("Bearer"))
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = auth_token;
        else {
            request.Headers["x-access_type"] = "offline";
            request.Headers["x-zumo-auth"] = auth_token;
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null).Result;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var typ = typeof(T);
            if (
                typ == typeof(String)
                || typ == typeof(float)
                || typ == typeof(Decimal)
                || typ == typeof(Int16)
                || typ == typeof(Int32)
                || typ == typeof(Int64)
            )
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T), null);
            }
            return result.FromJson<T>();

        }

        catch (AggregateException agEx)
        {
            AggregateException(agEx);
            return result.FromJson<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return result.FromJson<T>();
        }
    }
```

This is the call from ViewModel

```
    public async Task GetAllItems()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.IsInternetConnectionAvailable())
            {
                await this.CurrentContentPage.DisplayAlert("", AppResources.InternetConnectionNotAvailable, AppResources.Ok);
                return;
            }
            this.ProgressBar.ShowProgress(AppResources.Loading);

            ItemList = await this.ItemService.GetItemsByID(App.Locator.Login.LoggedInUser.TenantID.ToString(),Settings.AuthToken);
            if (ItemList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.ItemList.Count; i++)
                {
                    ItemList[i].RowColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? Theme.EvenRowColor : Theme.OddRowColor);
                }
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemList");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(CurrentContentPage, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.ProgressBar.Dismiss();                
        }
    }
```

In actual case here - the ProgressBar will kept on be displayed on the device, though its in Finally block. User have to kill the application to make it work again.
And we're unsuccessful to reproduce this back in lab. It only happens on field during intermittent connections.

Any abnormalities in the code? If not, how can we capture this in application log.

Comment: I see you are adding the ZUMO-API-VERSION but you aren't using the Azure Mobile Apps SDK.  Is this intentional?  (Removed the azure-mobile-services tag)

Comment: You can instrument your app in any number of ways.  Personally, I use the free Visual Studio Mobile Center Analytics - you can use Log Flow to take a look at analytics coming in from the device.  See https://mobile.azure.com

Comment: @AdrianHall - we need to specify the ZUMO-API-VERSION key - else it will throw error :
  "message": "No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'. "

Comment: @AdrianHall is the VS Mobile Center Analytics any different from HockeyApp? We have HockeyApp enabled but this issue in not captures in there.

Comment: VS Mobile Center Analytics has both crash reporting and analytics - you said it didn't crash, but it will provide you an opportunity to log things internal on your mobile device.